# Allow member function for a specific type only

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I am using C++ and templates - but I need to allow using a member function for a specific type and prevent other types from using this function.

For example: I want this class to have `print()` for all types but have `foo()` for just type `int`. How can I do that ?

```
#include<iostream>

template <class type>
class example
{
private:
    type data;

public:
    void print(); // for all types

    void foo();   // only for 'type' == int?
};
```

Comment: Don't use templates?  Seems like templates are the wrong tool if you just want to allow methods to apply to specific types.  Post sample code to get better answers.

Comment: Post some minimal code. As I see it, you have two possibilities: Use various interfaces, or use function overloading based on parameter type.

Comment: Take a look at `std::enable_if`,  it probably does what you want.

Comment: I edited the question. Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 4):

Factor the common, generic functionality into a base class. Specializations can inherit that.

```
namespace detail {

template <class type>
class example_base
{
private:
type data ;

public:
void print();
};

} // end namespace detail

template <class type>
struct example
    : detail::example_base<type> {
    using detail::example_base<type>::example_base; // inherit any constructors
};

template <> // specialize the class
struct example< int >
    : detail::example_base<int> {
    using detail::example_base<int>::example_base; // inherit any constructors

    void other_function(); // extend the basic functionality
};
```

Comment: but I need the same class name

Comment: Youssef, specializations need not inherit from it. You could still have the same name if you use full specialization.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, As the Op requires the same name, I propose modifying the solution to use full specialisation:

Comment: @YoussefEmad I'm not sure what you mean by that. The interface here is still called `example<T>`. The class `example_base` is not presented to the user. I've edited the answer to put it in a namespace, to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::enable_if` and do something like this to obtain exactly what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class example
{
   private:
      T data;
   public:
      void print() 
      { 
         std::cout << " hello " << std::endl;
      }

      template<class U = T // make the function templated on U, but with default type T
             , typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = nullptr // enable only for when U (T) is an integral type
             >
      void foo()
      {
         std::cout << " I will only compile when T is an integral type " << std::endl;
      }
};


int main()
{
   example<int> integer_example;
   integer_example.print();
   integer_example.foo(); // <--- compiles fine as int is integral

   example<double> double_example;
   double_example.print();
   //double_example.foo(); // <--- will not compile

   return 0;
}
```

In the `std::enable_if` you can also put `std::is_same<U,int>::value` instead of `std::is_integral<U>::value` to only allow the function only to be used for `int` and not other integral types.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the template for some types. See this example :

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
  private:
    double my_function() { return 1.0; }
};

template <>
class MyClass<double>
{
  public:
    double my_function() { return 2.0; }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass<double> a;
  MyClass<int> b;
  double x = a.my_function();  // this works
  // double y = b.my_function(); // not allowed
  return 0;
}
```

Tested with GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: How does this handle the common function case?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. But it can be used as a sub class providing the functionnality.

Comment: This means that If I have 10 common functions and a unique one I will have to rewrite the 10 functions again

Comment: You can inherit from a class providing the common 10 functions.

Comment: @Caduchon That is my answer :) .